# given origin and radii, how to find out if p(x,y,z) is inside torus?

Tags: 3d, lua, geometry

Im trying to create a 3D torus in a block game, so i need to evaluate a range of coordinates to see if they are inside a torus. The way i did it with spheres is:

```
shapefunc = function (pos,fields)
  map = {}
  pos.x = math.floor(pos.x+0.5)
  pos.y = math.floor(pos.y+0.5)
  pos.z = math.floor(pos.z+0.5)

  for x=-fields.radius,fields.radius do
    for y=-fields.radius,fields.radius do
      for z=-fields.radius,fields.radius do
        if x*x+y*y+z*z <= fields.radius*fields.radius then
          table.insert(map,{x=pos.x+x,y=pos.y+y,z=pos.z+z})
        end
      end
    end
  end
  return map
end
```

given height (on y axis), a minor and major radius (on xz axes), and a point of origin, none of the evaluation expressions i tried have given me anything close to a torus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/jXf71566HVU) it's a matter of testing for the sign of the expression:

(x^2+y^2+z^2-(a^2+b^2))^2 - 4*a*b*(b^2-z^2)

where the point is {x,y,z} and the minor radius of the torus is b, and the major radius a.

Comment: @user1836708, looks good. If it works for you, you may want to accept the answer.

Comment: Im new to this site - how do i do that? also, can you recommend similar resources for geometry (same kind of formulas for other shapes) ?

Comment: @user1836708, on [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23138/how-to-accept-the-answer-on-stack-overflow); on finding resources for geometry formulas, I'd just use google for "point inside X" (I tried on several, like "point inside pyramid" and they worked well).

Answer (score 2):

The formula above didn't work for me. Consider b = 0, the formula should reduce to a circle, when in fact in the accepted answer it reduces to a sphere.

From my calculation you must test the sign of the expression

(x^2+y^2+z^2+a^2-b^2)^2-4a^2(x^2+y^2)

where the point is {x,y,z} and the minor radius of the torus is b, and the major radius a.

edit: equivalently, and closer to the original accepted answer the expression would be

(x^2+y^2+z^2-(a^2+b^2))^2-4a^2(b^2-z^2)

Answer (score 0):

The solution by Paul didn't work for me. Instead, I came up with this simple working solution in Python:

```py
def INSIDE_TORUS(p):
    angle_xy = np.arctan2(p[1], p[0])
    p = [p[0] - TOROIDAL_RADIUS * np.cos(angle_xy), p[1] - TOROIDAL_RADIUS * np.sin(angle_xy), p[2]]
    return -POLOIDAL_RADIUS <= np.linalg.norm(p) <= POLOIDAL_RADIUS
```

where `TOROIDAL_RADIUS` is the major radius, and `POLOIDAL_RADIUS` is the minor radius.
The torus is assumed to be centered around the origin and its major radius is located in the XY plane.

It works by simply "pulling back" the minor circle into the origin by subtracting the major radius vector.
Then we can just check if the point `p` is inside the minor circle.

For this to work, the angle in the XY plane is first calculated, using `np.arctan2(y, x)`.